# User not logged in, into Facebook page plugin in UIWebView app

Tags: facebook, swift, uiwebview, facebook-login, fbsdk

Inside an iOS app, which is an `(UIWebView)` app for a website, we have our fb page embedded into it using `facebook page plugin`.

The user logs into the app using facebook.

When user logs in, beside the like/share button it shows `signup to see what your friends like`. But, the user has already logged in.

Why is the user not logged into the facebook page plugin??

**iOS app design:**
There are two view controllers in the app
1. ViewController
2. ViewTwo
1. **ViewController:** It is the login page. Here the user logs into the app then we send the token to server. After logging in, using `performSegueWithIdentifier` ViewTwo controller is shown. `FB iOS SDK` is used for login.
2. **ViewTwo:** Here website is loaded into the webview. Here is where the facebook page plugin is in the website.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no connection whatsoever between your app and the webview, that would allow to pass the login information from the former to the latter.

Comment: @CBroe : Yeah. But it is not. Works well in iOS safari. But every time we click on `like` it fails first time and like changes to `confirm`. and clicking on `confirm` opens a `popup or a tab` with the post, like and cancel buttons.